# How to build a Flutter aar in debug mode

Tags: android, flutter, aar

I have a Flutter project with a native Android layer. The native Android layer have used to communicate with a client's target app. I'm building an aar file for them, and now I need to build the aar in debug mode. But when I run `'./gradlew assembleDebug'`, I got two files: `library-debug.aar` and `library-release.aar`, both of them contain inside BuildConfig with DEBUG=false.

**How build library-debug.aar with DEBUG=true?**

[image]

Comment: You should actually check your `classes.jar` file. You're checking the flutter library's jar file.

Comment: @Mahdi-Malv in `classes.jar` also debug=false